# What is the right approach to unittest this method in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, beautifulsoup, architecture

I have a scraping module on my application that uses Beautiful Soup and Selenium to get website info with this function:

```
def get_page(user: str) -> Optional[BeautifulSoup]:
    """Get a Beautiful Soup object that represents the user profile page in some website"""

    try:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        browser.get('https://somewebsite.com/' + user)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'article')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("User hasn't been found. Try another user.")
        return None
    return BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
```

I need to test this function in two ways:

- if it is getting a page (the success case);
- and if it is printing the warning and returning None when it's not getting any page (the failure case).

I tried to test like this:

```
class ScrapeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_page_success(self):
        """
        Test if get_page is getting a page
        """
        self.assertEqual(isinstance(sc.get_page('myusername'), BeautifulSoup), True)

    def test_get_page_not_found(self):
        """
        Test if get_page returns False when looking for a user
        that doesn't exist
        """
        self.assertEqual(sc.get_page('iwçl9239jaçklsdjf'), None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Doing it like that makes the tests somewhat slower, as `get_page` itself is slow in the success case, and in the failure case, I'm forcing a timeout error looking for a non-existing user. I have the impression that my approach for testing these functions is not the right one. Probably the best way to test it is to **fake** a response, so `get_page` won't need to connect to the server and ask for anything.

So I have two questions:

1. Is this "fake web response" idea the right approach to test this function?
2. If so, how can I achieve it for that function? Do I need to rewrite the `get_page` function so it can be "testable"?

---

EDIT:

I tried to create a test to `get_page` like this:

```
class ScrapeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.driver = mock.patch(
            'scrape.webdriver.Chrome',
            autospec=True
        )
        self.driver.page_source.return_value = "<html><head></head><body><article>Yes</article></body></html>"
        self.driver.start()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.driver.stop()

    def test_get_page_success(self):
        """
        Test if get_page is getting a page
        """
        self.assertEqual(isinstance(sc.get_page('whatever'), BeautifulSoup), True)
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `driver.page_source` attribute is created only after the `wait.until` function call. I need the `wait.until` because I need that Selenium browser waits for the javascript to create the `article` tags in HTML in order for me to **scrape** them.

When I try to define a return value for page source in `setUp`, I get an error: `AttributeError: '_patch' object has no attribute 'page_source'`

I tried lots of ways to mock webdriver attributes with `mock. patch` but it seems very difficult to my little knowledge. I think that maybe the best way to achieve what I desire (test `get_page` function without the need to connect to a server) is to mock an entire web server connection. But this is just a guess.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365346/preferred-approach-to-mock-a-site-to-test-a-scraper for a discussion of this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are on the right track with #1. Look into the `mock` library which allows you to mock (fake) out functions, methods and classes and control the results of method calls. This will also remove the latency of the actual calls.

In my experience it is best to focus on testing the local logic and mock out any external dependencies. If you do that you will have a lot of small unit tests that together will test the majority of your code.

Based on your update, try:

```
self.driver = mock.patch_object(webdriver.Chrome, 'page_source', return_value="<html><head></head><body><article>Yes</article></body></html>"
```

If that doesn't work, then unfortunately I am out of ideas. I't possible the Selenium code is harder to mock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question is: I tried to mock the `webdriver.Chrome.get` function,  with no success. Reading this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061125/mocking-requests-sent-by-the-selenium-webdriver-in-python-and-having-the-fake-re) I saw that the approach suggested is using the `pytest-localserver` module to fake a webserver connection, instead of mocking Selenium functions directly, which seems more difficult. How can I do it using `unittest` instead of `pytest`? Or I really need to rely on `pytest` to do so?

Comment: In my experience, when mocking, it can be somewhat challenging to find the correct place to mock out. I'm not familiar with the Selenium framework so I can't say exactly how to do it.  In the SO question you linked to, I don't see them actually using the `mock` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) which is part of `unittest`.  Did you use the `mock` library and if so, what was the stack trace of the errors you saw?

Comment: Yes, I used mock.patch to create a test. See the edit in my question.

Comment: In the question I linked they're using `pytest` that has a module called `pytest.localserver` and they fake a server and give mock responses to Selenium webdriver. I think this could be a solution, but I really don't want to switch my project to `pytest` right now.

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Comment: Many thanks, this code does not work. And yes, Selenium is very complicated. I'm studying pytest with hope that this could be a solution.